# My parameterized insertion is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

My code for parameterized data insertion is not working. I get the error:

```
'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'Parameter' and no extension method 'Parameter' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I added `using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` but it made no difference. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;    

public partial class add_data_ch1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\qwhizz_ch1_Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into data_Table values (@fname, @lname, con);
        cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@fname", fnameTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@lname", lnameTextBox.Text);            
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();              
    }        
}
```

Would appreciate if someone can show me where the code error is or what is missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try **Parameters** instead of **Parameter**

Comment: @code: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be Parameters

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fnameTextBox.Text);
//Add rest of Parameters here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into data_Table values (@fname, @lname, con);
```

I believe you're just missing an end parenthesis and quotation marks.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into data_Table values (@fname, @lname)", con);
```

Comment: Hiss error says its for a definition in the SQLCommand CLass

Comment: If it was a parenthesis Visual Studios Wwould have kicked an error\

Comment: yes, code you are correct, as is your answer. Should be Parameters.